# Android contact manipulation

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, contacts, accountmanager

I'm developing an IM app on Android. The aim is to have multi accounts and protocols compatibility. 
I'm looking for a way to get the best status of a contact on Android.
I've got a list of account types supported. I have a function that takes a long (`contact_id`) and must return the best `Account` + best way to contact (e.g. `somebody@jabber.org`).

I already looked the documentation, and I know SQL already. But the documentation is a little messy on that point and I don't know how to get the best way to send a message to a contact. Here is some code of what I'm trying to do:

```java
public static Account best(Context context, long contact)
{
    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    final Cursor rawContacts = resolver.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
              new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
              RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + registeredProtocolsSelection(),
              new String[]{String.valueOf(contact)}, null);
    while(rawContacts.moveToNext())
    {
        final long rawContactId = rawContacts.getLong(0);
        Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
        Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor rawContact = resolver.query(entityUri,
                  new String[]{RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1},
                  null, null, null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I can select all RawContacts that matter for my app but then I don't know how to join and I can't get a clear schema of the database. I don't know how to access StatusUpdate from there. The aim is like `ORDER BY presence`.

Is there an easy way to do that? Is there a way to manipulate Contacts like normal Object via something like an ORM? Or do we have a mechanism to create and manage our own IM protocols easily on Android?

Comment: I found during my research ORMLite that can greatly help me. Does anyone knows the schema of the sqlite DB for contacts in Android ?
Or better does anyone know about a Contact class with the correct annotations to get the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With time I found it. We can use the last parameter of ContentProvider.query(..., sort); to have the best RawContact Presence first for a given Contact. For those who still search here is the code

```
final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query
(
    StatusUpdates.CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[]
    {
        StatusUpdates.PRESENCE,
        StatusUpdates.STATUS_LABEL,
        StatusUpdates.STATUS_RES_PACKAGE
    }, 
    Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
    new String[]
    { 
        Long.toString(id), 
        CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE 
    },
    StatusUpdates.STATUS_TIMESTAMP + " DESC" // For last Or
    StatusUpdates.PRESENCE + " DESC" // For presence
);
if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    presence = Presence.get(cursor.getLong(0));
    status = Utils.Contact.status(cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getString(2));
}
if(cursor!=null)
{
    cursor.close();
}
```

You can also use the predifined field of the contact table with automatic best status for a given contact.